# c, control reaches end of non-void function in c

Tags: c, function, warnings, void

I have `dispatchQueue.c:215: warning: control reaches end of non-void function` warning from the code below.. 
Can anyone please explain why?

```
void *dispatcher_threadloop(void *arg){

//thread loop of the dispatch thread- pass the tast to one of worker thread

dispatch_queue_thread_t *dThread = arg;
dispatch_queue_t *dQueue;
dQueue = dThread->queue;

if (dQueue->HEAD!=NULL){
    for(;;){
        printf("test");
        sem_wait(&(dQueue->queue_task_semaphore));
        dThread->current_task = dQueue->HEAD;
        dQueue->HEAD =  dQueue->HEAD->next;
        dQueue->HEAD->prev = NULL;
        sem_post(&(dQueue->queue_task_semaphore));
        break;
        //TODO
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, imagine what happens if `dQueue->HEAD` is `NULL`: the `if` won't be entered, so you get to the end of the function which is supposed to return a `void*` - but you don't return anything.

Try returning some sensible value at the bottom of your function to fix this. Or add an assertion which states that this code should be unreachable, like:

```
assert( !"Unreachable code hit" );
```

Answer (score 14):

Because you are declaring it `void *` (not `void`) and **not returning anything**. Return `NULL` if you don’t need any return value.

```
void *dispatcher_threadloop(void *arg)
```

Answer (score 4):

The signature for your function indicates it returns a `void *`, which is a pointer and is different than `void`.

If your function isn't meant to return anything, use `void`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but if someone's trying to figure this out (for pthreads), you MAY want to return:

- `pthread_exit(void *retval)` (For joinable threads)
- `pthread_exit(NULL)` (For detached threads)

Answer (score 1):

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/topic/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtpm1/m1rhnvf.html

> This warning is similar to the warning described in Return with no value. If control reaches the end of a function and no return is encountered, GCC assumes a return with no return value. However, for this, the function requires a return value. At the end of the function, add a return statement that returns a suitable return value, even if control never reaches there.

From the prototype it seems you want to return something.